# Building Qt application for mupltiple linux distributions

Tags: linux, qt, g++, static-linking

I'm using Qt for developing a cross-platform app which must not depend on OS pre-installed libraries. I didn't have any problems with Windows: all I needed to do is to copy .dll files into executable file directory. For various linux-based systems I'm using a script which does the following steps:

1. Runs `qmake`
2. Appends `-Wl,-rpath,./` to `LFLAGS` directive of Makefile, making dependency search running in current directory as well
3. Runs make
4. Gets all of application dependencies using `ldd -v -r` and copies executable file with its dependencies into another folder

Running application goes well on the fresh install (without Qt) of the same OS (and same version) on which the app was build, but running it on another OS/another version fails due to some errors.

Building without dependencies isn't a viable option as the application may be used on machines without internet access and/or pre-installed Qt.
And I can't use static build either because QWebKit is required and it doesn't support static build.

Different combinations of the system on which I build the app and the system on which I'm trying to run it give different errors:

```
relocation error: ./libcrypto.so.7: symbol __libc_enable_secure, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference

relocation error: ./libc.so.6: symbol __libc_enable_secure, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are probably trying to compile on a newer version of Linux/glibc/binutils than you try to run on. It never really worked well. The easiest way to make it work is installing an old Linux version (think 2005) and compiling on that. This problem has nothing to do with qt or g++ or static linking by the way. It's purely a glibc/binutils issue.

Comment: was that ALT Linux, by chance? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is viable, there are too many problems with just having your own libraries bundled for everything. Commercial vendors normally have a short list of explicitly supported platforms (distribution + version + architecture combos).

For each platform, use system Qt if such is available and appropriate. For example, on RHEL6/CentOS6, the system Qt is 4.6.2, so you may want to link with your own Qt compiled on CentOS6.

The way it should be done is to have continuous integration system in place, so that you have the target distributions in virtual machines, and an automated script compiles and runs tests on all of them. This doesn't have to be very complex, at a minimum you need a cron script running in each of the VMs, emailing/uploading the results, and a configuration/script to start all the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

At a very high level, the best way to do this is use the concept of 'fat binaries'. Essentially you are bundling (for example) a RHEL 6.5, a SUSE 10, and a Ubuntu 12 binary into the same file. Then you can build a very simple stub that would query /etc/issue and determine the actual host distribution at runtime and run the correct binary. Years ago NextStep used this for supporting x86 and Motorola platforms in the same 'file'. The exact details of how to do this I don't have, but I'll bet a scripting  lang. like python or perl, or even bash could handle the stub part.